# How to update status in Attask Workfront through API calls

Tags: api, attask, workfront-api

I have been trying to use 
PUT .../api/v4.0/task?updates=[{"ID":"XYX","status":"InProgress"}
Do we need to add any other headers other than Content-Type? 
I am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it.

PUT .../api/v4.0/task/{ID}?fields=parameterValues&updates={"status": "INP"}

That would change the status from New to INProgress. The main thing was abbreviation for InProgress is INP and also adding fields.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you must use the key for the status.  You can get these from the API metadate with the status enum or you can get them from the interface from Setup -> Project Prefs -> Statuses.

They are case sensitive.